# how do i create generate a whitesource_report.html in azure pipelines using whitesource not whitesource-bolt

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using the whitesource unified agent in azure pipelines but I can't generate a whitesource_report.html

```
- task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Task - Mend Unified Agent Scan'
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            curl -LJO https://unified-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/wss-unified-agent.jar
            echo Unified Agent downloaded successfully
            java -jar wss-unified-agent.jar -c whitesource.config -out whitesource_report.html
        env:
          WS_APIKEY: '${{ parameters.WsApiKey }}'
          WS_USERKEY: '${{ parameters.WsUserKey }}'
          WS_WSS_URL: '${{ parameters.WssUrl }}'
          WS_PRODUCTNAME: '${{ parameters.WsProductName }}'
          WS_PROJECTNAME: '${{ parameters.WsProjectName }}'
          WS_SERVICECONNECTION: '${{ parameters.WsApiKey }}'
          WS_ENABLEIMPACTANALYSIS: false
          WS_REQUIREKNOWNSHA1: true
          WS_NUGET_RESOLVEDEPENDENCIES: true
          WS_NUGET_RUNPRESTEP: true
          WS_FILESYSTEMSCAN: false
          WS_GENERATEPROJECTDETAILSJSON: true
          WS_EXCLUDES: '${{ parameters.WsExcludes }}'
          WS_PROJECTAG: '${{ parameters.WsProjecTag }}'
          WS_FOLLOWSYMBOLICLINKS: true
          WS_FAILONPOLICYVIOLATION: true
          WS_CHECKPOLICIES: true
          WS_FORCECHECKALLDEPENDENCIES: true
          WS_FORCEUPDATE: true
          WS_SCANCOMMENT: '${{ parameters.WscanComment }}'
          WS_SENDLOGSTOWSS: true
```

i tried running this script inside a powershell@2 task
java -jar wss-unified-agent.jar -c whitesource.config -out whitesource_report.html

and i wask expecting it to create an the html file but instead i got this output:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0  118M    0 16384    0     0  12962      0  2:39:18  0:00:01  2:39:17 12951
  0  118M    0  457k    0     0   209k      0  0:09:37  0:00:02  0:09:35  209k
  7  118M    7 8820k    0     0  2775k      0  0:00:43  0:00:03  0:00:40 2774k
 17  118M   17 20.9M    0     0  5049k      0  0:00:23  0:00:04  0:00:19 5048k
 27  118M   27 32.4M    0     0  6424k      0  0:00:18  0:00:05  0:00:13 6784k
 38  118M   38 45.8M    0     0  7610k      0  0:00:15  0:00:06  0:00:09 9569k
 49  118M   49 58.4M    0     0  8237k      0  0:00:14  0:00:07  0:00:07 11.4M
 59  118M   59 70.0M    0     0  8748k      0  0:00:13  0:00:08  0:00:05 12.2M
 70  118M   70 83.8M    0     0  9363k      0  0:00:12  0:00:09  0:00:03 12.7M
 81  118M   81 96.4M    0     0  9618k      0  0:00:12  0:00:10  0:00:02 12.5M
 91  118M   91  107M    0     0  9870k      0  0:00:12  0:00:11  0:00:01 12.3M
100  118M  100  118M    0     0   9.9M      0  0:00:11  0:00:11 --:--:-- 12.8M
Unified
Agent
downloaded
successfully
```

the download was successful but upon executing java -jar wss-unified-agent.jar -c whitesource.config -out whitesource_report.html this error happened

```
[WARN] [2023-02-23 03:46:53,528 +0000] - Error parsing command lines parameters, error message: Was passed main parameter '-out' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class
please make sure to use <key> <value> command line parameters format
When using PowerShell, please make sure to use '_' (underscore) instead of '.' (dot) for relevant configuration parameters
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have installed the WhiteSource Bolt extension for Azure DevOps from the Azure Marketplace.

Configure the WhiteSource Bolt extension in your Azure DevOps organization and project. You will need to provide your WhiteSource API token and other required information in the WhiteSource Bolt extension configuration.

Add a task to your Azure Pipelines YAML file that runs the WhiteSource Bolt scan. This task should reference the configuration you set up. For Example this is the YAML file for running the scan. :

```
- task: whitesource-bolt@21
  displayName: 'WhiteSource Bolt Scan'
  inputs:
    apiKey: '<your WhiteSource API key>'
    productToken: '<your WhiteSource product token>'
    checkPolicies: true
    failBuildOnPolicyViolation: true
```

Add a task to your YAML file that generates the whitesource_report.html file. You can use the whitesource-fail-on-policy command from the WhiteSource Bolt CLI to generate the report in HTML format. YAML code for generating report:

```
- script: |
    whitesource-fail-on-policy -apiKey <your WhiteSource API key> -productToken <your WhiteSource product token> -projectName "<your project name>" -projectVersion "<your project version>" -reportDirectory "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
  displayName: 'Generate WhiteSource Report'
```

Note that the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) variable is used to specify the directory where the report will be generated. This directory is automatically created by Azure Pipelines and is used to store build artifacts.

Publish the whitesource_report.html file as an artifact in Azure Pipelines. For publishing the artifact :

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish WhiteSource Report'
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'WhiteSource Report'
    artifactType: 'Container'
    containerFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: sadly the organization specifically uses whitesource/mend not white source bolt. does this also work with whitesource@21?

Comment: I think you can, im not sure about it. But you can give a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is for using without whitesource bolt.

Install the WhiteSource Unified Agent on your build machine or use a Docker image that includes the WhiteSource Unified Agent.

Configure the WhiteSource Unified Agent with your WhiteSource API token and other required information. You can do this by creating a configuration file (e.g. whitesource.config) in your project directory or by using environment variables.

Add a step to your Azure Pipelines YAML file that runs the WhiteSource Unified Agent in a yaml file.

```
- script: |
    whitesource.sh -c whitesource.config -apiKey <your WhiteSource API key> -product <your product name> -project <your project name> -projectVersion <your project version> -d . -logLevel INFO
  displayName: 'WhiteSource Scan'
```

The -d . option specifies the directory to scan (the current directory) and the -logLevel INFO option sets the logging level to INFO.

Add a step to your YAML file that generates the whitesource_report.html file. You can use the whitesourceReport.py script from the WhiteSource Unified Agent to generate the report in HTML format. For generating the report :

```
- script: |
    python3 /path/to/whitesource-agent/agent/whitesource/whitesourceReport.py -a . -d . -o whitesource_report.html
  displayName: 'Generate WhiteSource Report'
```

The -a . option specifies the directory containing the WhiteSource scan results and the -o whitesource_report.html option specifies the output file name.

Publish the whitesource_report.html file as an artifact in Azure Pipelines. To publish the artifact :

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish WhiteSource Report'
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'WhiteSource Report'
    artifactType: 'Container'
    containerFolder: '.'
    contents: |
      whitesource_report.html
```

This task will publish the whitesource_report.html file as an artifact in Azure Pipelines, which can then be downloaded and viewed by team members.

I think this should work. :)

Comment: Hi, where about can whitesourceReport.py be found? The unified agent as far as I'm aware downloaded as a jar?